# Empty activity when resuming after onBackPressed in Android

Tags: java, android

I have got a strange problem with my Android app.

**How my app works:** When I start my app it launches the MainActivity. If the user is not logged in it then launches LoginActivity and after that finish is called in the MainActivity.

Now when the LoginActivity is launched and I press the back button the app closes. When I open the app again it has to launch the LoginActivity again, but sometimes this is not working (like 1 of the 8 times). When it doesn't work the app just shows me an empty activity.

When the app doesn't launch correctly (2nd printscreen) the buttons/text inputs do work, but it looks like they are just hidden or something. So when I press at the position of the '*Sign Up*' text it does take me to the RegisterActivity.

Does somebody know what causes this strange behaviour?

This is when the app is launched correctly:
[image: Good launch]

But this is what happens sometimes:
[image: Bad launch]

**MainActivity onCreate:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initializeDataSources();

    if(usersDataSource.getCurrentUser() == null)
    {
        Intent LoginActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        LoginActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(LoginActivity);
        finish();
        return;
    }

    if(localServiceBinder == null)
        localServiceBinder = new LocalServiceBinder();

    bindLocalService();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

**LoginActivity onCreate:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(localServiceBinder == null)
        localServiceBinder = new LocalServiceBinder();

    bindLocalService();

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mUsernameView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    mSignUpButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_button);
}
```

Comment: can be  `usersDataSource.getCurrentUser() != null` the case?

Comment: No, I just tested it with if(true) so it always launches the LoginActivity, but I still got the same problem.

Comment: Are you talking to a server with your `Service`?

Comment: what looks really strange is that the blank activity has the title

Comment: @Emmanuel The service does contain code to talk to a server, but this code isn't used until you press the login button.

Comment: @blackbelt Yeah I know, but when I Log.d(TAG, "i'm here") just after requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); it does log "i'm here"

Answer (score 0):

Move your data work and login activity call to onStart/onResume.
You get "empty" activity when onDestroy/onCreate dont calls when activity hide and shows again.
When this: `if(usersDataSource.getCurrentUser() == null)` 
is true, this:

```
if(localServiceBinder == null)
            localServiceBinder = new LocalServiceBinder();

bindLocalService();

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

became a dead code for case: onPause -> onStop -> onStart -> onResume
in lifecycle of your activity.

Comment: This is not working, I still got the same problem. Also if if(usersDataSource.getCurrentUser() == null) is true the MainActivity closes and the LoginActivity is started. So the rest of the code should be dead code.

Comment: its closes but not always destroys

Comment: If you put login activity call in onStart without checking user data - it works? I think it must. Then may be user data (which you must also init in onStart) depends on the old MainActivity instance. There is not so many cases. You exactly have a situation when your MainActivity instance was created once, shown LoginActivity, and when you call application second time - did't call onCreate, because old instance was not destroyed.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work either. The strange think is that it does launch the LoginActivity. I can click the buttons on the empty screen although I can't see them.